# Почему не отображаются props?

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь отдать переменную "data" через "BookServiceProvider", но почему-то получаю undefined

1. В index.js - создаю data - HelloWorld, отдаю ее в провайдер
2. В /hoc/with-bookstore-service.js/ обрабатываю data
3. В app.js пытаюсь вывести из props dat'y в консоль, но получаю
   undefined

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-knuth-pmlu8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В провайдер, данные надо передавать в аргументе `value`, т.е.

```
<BookServiceProvider value={data} >
```

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider